# CF - Shortcut in Programs folder on device

Tags: c#, deployment, compact-framework, shortcut

On my CAB project i have added a Programs folder and created a shortcut for it.

Can i add a icon for the shortcut and how can i do it if so.

thanx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot explicitly set the icon for the shortcut in Windows CE.  The shortcut icon will be the same as the target application's icon.